# Wikipedia Sync Reading Lists not working?

Tags: applications, sync

I have been using the Saved Reading Lists feature on the Wikipedia Android app for a long time. At this point, however, I have different versions of my saved Lists on my Android phone vs. my Android tablet.

I noticed (in the Android app), that if you go into Saved and touch the top right-hand three dots, the last item is Refresh Sync with a Last Sync date. In my settings, I have Reading list syncing enabled on both my phone and tablet (in the Android app on both devices).

In the Wikipedia app, on both devices, in Saved, the categories are listed: first is listed Saved (the Default list), and then each category I created. The various categories that I created between my phone and tablet are now not synced: some of the category names are the same and some are different. Similarly, if I compare the Articles within the Saved category on one device vs. the other, some of the same articles appear in both, and some articles appear on only one device's Saved category. If I compare the articles within a Created Category that has the same name in the app on one device vs. the other, some Created Categories have the exact same articles, and some Created Categories have differences in the specific articles.

I was expecting that when sync is activated, it would at least sync up the specific articles within the Saved categories, and possibly, at least the categories that have the same names. In other words, adding the articles that are missing from Saved and same-named categories between the apps in the two devices. (If it would add missing created categories between the two devices also, that would be even better). Instead, when I touch Sync (in the app on either device) it does nothing! Even the Last Sync date does not change, even though I get the message (at the bottom of the screen): Reading Lists Synced.

I noticed in Settings, under Syncing, there is also a setting: Download Reading list articles. In the app on both devices, I had this enabled. To test whether this might be disabling syncing, I disabled this setting on both devices. Then Synced again, on one device - no change in the articles on the opposite device. Then sync again, the opposite device, and still no change in articles. I also added a new article to Saved, and a new one to the same-named category on my phone... Synced again on both devices, and again, the two articles were not added on the tablet side. (Thus disabling Download Reading list articles, does not change the result).

I also tried adding the Firefox extension Wikipedia Reading Lists to Firefox on my Windows 10 laptop. I tried adding a new article there - which apparently can only be added to the Default Saved list. I get the success message on the laptop, but the new article does not appear in the Saved category in the app on either device - even after running Sync on each app. Even closing and reopening each app on each device (after each operation mentioned above) after syncing does not help.

Lastly, I noticed there is an export function available after going into any category (the Default Saved or a created one), and this does create a .json file in the download folder in internal memory on the device you run it on. But I don't see any import function that you could use to transfer the articles from a category on one device to the same-named category on the other device!

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I have a suspicion that the sync feature might be *per-device* (i.e. same device backup & restore), not global (i.e. all-devices synchronization), but I haven't used the app, so it's only a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Andrew, and thanks also for migrating my question. I just notice, that actually there is an import link. It is available after touching the 3 dots when you first go into Saved (and viewing all the lists). So I think I'm going to try using that along with the export I found before. I'll post the results after trying it...